# Reply to transactional email Magento 1

Tags: email, magento, magento2, magento-1.9, transactional-email

I have a question about transactional emails in Magento 1.9. The transactional email have a reply-to set to no-reply@domain.com. How can I change that to be sales@domain.com? I have the same problem with another site that is built with Magento 2.3.
I saw this code but I don't know if it is good or where I can put it:

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mailTemplate->setReplyTo('test@example.com');
$mailTemplate->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recipient, '', $vars, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, all email addresses can be configured from `System->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses`